# Get whitespace in XElement

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-xml, whitespace, xelement

I know this is a bit stupid, but XML I'm transforming sometimes has an element that is just a single or double whitespace. Like this:

```
Dim es1 = <Text> </Text>
```

When I try to get the `.Value` of this like `Dim resultText = es1.Value`, it's just an empty string. This isn't a problem if there is leading and/or trailing whitespace and at least one other character in the element.

Is there anyway to coerce `.Value` to give me white space if that is all there is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` when you parse the XML. C# sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<Foo> </Foo>";

        XElement withWhitespace = XElement.Parse(xml,
            LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
        Console.WriteLine(withWhitespace.Value.Length); // Prints 1
        XElement withoutWhitespace = XElement.Parse(xml);
        Console.WriteLine(withoutWhitespace.Value.Length); // Prints 0

    }
}
```

(Obviously this is available when using `Load` as well as `Parse`, etc.)

I don't know how that fits in with VB XML literals, but I'll assume that normally you're actually parsing from a file etc :)

Answer (score 2):

Load your XDocument with:

```
LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace
```

Comment: rats.  Sniped by the great one.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a XML literal with white space use an embedded expression.  This example has two spaces.

```
    Dim TwoSpaces As XElement = <f><%= "  " %></f>
    Dim s As String = TwoSpaces.Value
```